# Update inside a read uncommitted transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I am having an SP with transaction isolation level set as Read Uncommitted.
For Example

```
Create Procedure TrailSP
AS
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
BEGIN TRY

UPDATE TrialTable
SET TrailColumn ='Update'
WHERE TrailID=1

--this is followed by more updates and selects

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

RETURN -1;
END CATCH

RETURN 0;
```

what I want to know is that the first update I have given in the SP will it get committed instantly as it executes or will it get committed along with the rest of the logic at the end of Sp.

Comment: Are you ok with missing and/or duplicate data in your procedure? Setting the isolation level to read uncommitted is like adding the nolock hint to every single query in your procedure. http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/11/10/1280.aspx

Comment: It is part of a standard format i have to use for store procedures.So,can't remove it

Comment: Are you saying that every one of your procedures uses that isolation level? You really need to read up on that hint and understand what it really means. It is NOT some magic "go fast" button. It means that none of your procedures are accurate. If accuracy is important then you need to get that practice removed from your company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will get committed, as any update under any transaction isolation level, when the **transaction commits**. This has *nothing* to do with the stored procedure ending.

If the call to your procedure has a transaction, then the commit will occur when *that* transaction commits.

If the call to your procedure does not have a transaction but the session has enabled [implicit transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) then it will commit when the application explicitly commits.

If the call to your procedure does not have a transaction and session has the auto commit transaction behavior (ie. the most common case) then transaction will commit when the UPDATE statement completes.

Enabling READ UNCOMMITTED for an UPDATE is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

-Any data read inside a READ UNCOMMITTED is data that could disappear because the transaction that wrote it rollback.

-Its also possible to not see some row that have been committed because a transaction that have not yet committed and might never commit deleted it.

-Its also possible for row to be missing or be duplicated because of PageSplit.

Basically anything is possible, so the data read should never be used to compute anything that should be written to the database or you risk corrupting your database.

TLDR: never use READ UNCOMMITTED